# How to access plugin method inside .each() jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [bxSlider](http://bxslider.com/) on my site. Here's my script :

```
handleBxSlider = function(){
    var initSliders, destroySliders;

    initSliders = function(){
        jQuery('.bxslider').each(function(){
            jQuery(this).bxSlider({
                slideWidth: 5000,
                minSlides: jQuery(this).attr("min-slides") || 4,
                maxSlides: jQuery(this).attr("min-slides") || 5,
                slideMargin: jQuery(this).attr("slide-margin") || 20
            });
        });
    };

    destroySliders = function(){
        initSliders.destroySlider();
    };

    initSliders();
    destroySliders();

};
```

[bxSlider](http://bxslider.com/) has method `destroySlider();`. I need to make all public methods in [bxSlider's](http://bxslider.com/) plugin to be accessible just by calling `handleBxSlider`.

It's like, `handleBxSlider.destroySlider();` to destroy sliders, or `handleBxSlider.initSliders();`, to re-init sliders.
But the `destroySliders();` didn't works. How to access public methods of bxSlider inside `initSliders function()` ?

Or is there any best solutions?

Anyway, here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FArIZzX77/5xx2ofbu/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `initSliders` you just creating `bxSlider` and you can't reach object in inner scope. I added array `sliderArray` where all slider object are. Now by calling `destroySliders` you can destroy sliders.

```
handleBxSlider = function () {
    var initSliders, destroySliders, sliderArray = [];

    initSliders = function () {
        jQuery('.bxslider').each(function () {
            var sliderObj = jQuery(this).bxSlider({
                slideWidth: 5000,
                minSlides: jQuery(this).attr("min-slides") || 4,
                maxSlides: jQuery(this).attr("min-slides") || 5,
                slideMargin: jQuery(this).attr("slide-margin") || 20
            });
            sliderArray.push(sliderObj)
        });
    };

    destroySliders = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < sliderArray.length; i++) {
            sliderArray[i].destroySlider();
        }
    };

    initSliders();
    destroySliders();
};
```

Comment: I've tried this, and didnt work. Here's [your script fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FArIZzX77/mv6ste3z/)

Comment: you `initSliders` and then `destroySliders`. Remove `destroySliders()`. works fine for me.

Comment: Thanks for replay. What if i want to recall `initSliders`?. I need to recall it after window resized event

Comment: if you `console.log(App)` you can see `App` inner scope functions. By adding `this` to `initSliders` you can reach from `App` scope by `App.initSliders()`.